# Handles vs Smart pointers. What to use?

Tags: c++, handle, smart-pointers

I'm starting to develop a graphical engine just for practicing purposes. One of the first questions that arised is either to use handles or smart pointers to refer to my class instances.

From my point of view:

- Smart pointers pros: created under demand, they do not have the problem of becoming stale pointers; cons: as they are in a linked list, searching for a pointer is an O(n) operation.
- Handles pros: search is O(1), object relocation is O(1); cons: can became stale pointers, creating a new handle forces the system to check for the first NULL entry in the handles table.

Which one to choose?  Please explain your selection.

EDITED:

I want to clarify some points after your comments and answers.

I don't mean smart pointers are a linked list in the way of "are represented by a STL linked list". I mean they behave, in some way as a linked list (if you move one object from one memory block to another, you need to iterate the full list of smart pointers to update all references to this object properly -it can be done with a linked list -).

And I don't mean handles exactly as opaque pointers or pointer to implementation models. I mean having a global handle table (an array of pointers) so when I request an object, I get a dereferenceable instance containing the index in this table where the actual pointer to the object can be found. So, if I move the object from one block to another, just updating the pointer entry in the handle table I get all pointers automatically updated at the same time.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what, exactly, you have in mind when you use the term "handle"?

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by "searching for a pointer", and why do you say smart pointers are stored in a linked list?

Comment: @davidcm: Usually a `handle` means an opaque entity(maybe pointer) which is used as a identifier, after the first initial call to open the device or file etc. Not sure, what kind of `handle` you are referring to here.

Comment: Why do you expect to be moving ojects around in memory like this?  Even in GC languages where the heap is periodically compacted, *you* don't rearrange the objects, the system does.

Comment: @DennisÇ: I'm targeting a very memory constrained platform so I need to write my own memory management system, that includes compacting memory blocks allocated for objects and data.

Comment: I think that your terminology is still very confused. If you call an array of pointers a "handle table", then surely you say "handle" meaning "pointer"? Then what is the difference?

Comment: Based on his comment (about compacting memory blocks), I think he's talking about using something like [MacOS (pre-X) memory model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_memory_management), where a handle is a pointer to a system-controlled and updated pointer in a "master pointer block" that can be updated in a centralized fashion when memory needs to be compacted.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of those definitions fit what's normally used. Smart pointers aren't in a linked-list in any way at all. Usually you use the observer pattern to keep a vector of raw pointers to objects that still exist if you need to iterate them or something. Handles as you describe them are pretty much only used for binary compatibility reasons and never in-process.

Use smart pointers, they take care of themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The term "handle" is a broad term that, essentially, means an *identifier to an object*.

A pointer or smart pointer falls under this definition, so you need to pick a terser term for your Option 2.

```
             "Handle"
                 |
          /------+-------\
         /       |         \
        /        |           \
    Pointer    Reference    Other Identififer
       |         |             \
  |----+----|   `T&`             \
  |         |                 |---+------|
 `T*`  `shared_ptr<T>`      Text       Number (e.g. HWND in WinAPI)
```

If I assume that you mean some fixed, memory-abstracted "other identifier" then, sure, you can employ this. You don't necessarily have an either/or scenario here. You probably want to use smart pointers *anyway* (for lifetime management if nothing else), and smart pointers don't *need* to be in a linked list.

You could have a `std::map<your_identifier_type, std::shared_ptr<T> >` to map your fixed, user-defined identifier to a [potentially-changing] smart pointer.

---

<sup>**Disclaimer:** This diagram was hastily drawn and represents my vision of the terminology tree as it stands now, half an hour after getting out of bed. There may be minor discrepancies with other views, but it should give a fairly reliable impression of things.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The biggest downside to handles is that unlike pointers, they require additional context to uniquely identify an object. For example, if handle is an index to an array, you need a pointer to that array to access the object. It complicates further if the array is dynamic and the base pointer may change. So one has to either use an implicit global/thread_local context, or use some kind of (base, offset) fat pointer which may be hard to pass to APIs expecting just a pointer (e.g. callbacks).